# How to use ABPersonView on Mac

Tags: macos, osx-lion

Do you know how to use ABPersonView on Mac?

I loaded people list in my address book on mac.

But I don't know how to show person detail view to use 'Address Book Person View'.

Can't use 'Address Book Person View' for mac application?

os x : 10.7.4
xcode : 4.3.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solve this myself.

- drag 'Address Book Person View' to container view.
- maybe 'Address Book Person View' changed to 'custom view' on container view.
- select 'custom view' in xib, and force change 'NSView' to 'ABPersonView' in class field in identity inspector
- force change 'custom view' to 'ABPersonView' in code and 'custom view' class.
- force import <AddressBook/ABPersonView.h>
- use this:

```
ABAddressBook* kAddressBook = [ABAddressBook addressBook];
ABPerson* kPerson = [kAddressBook.people objectAtIndex:row];
[personView setPerson:kPerson];
```

Answer (score 0):

the class in 107/108 has a bug with selecting a contact. it doesnt scroll to it so its often not visible

just a heads up:

http://www.openradar.me/radar?id=1854415